# Trying to prove that this function is continuous for all real numbers.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

The function in question is:  $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined
as $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \sqrt{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$

I am having a really hard time cracking this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you draw the graph of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Consider what's going on on $(m,m+1)$ and at $m$ separately, where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

On $(m,m+1)$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the constant function $m$ and $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is $x-m$ (which is $\geq0$, hence $\sqrt{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}\in\mathbb{R}$). So, $f(x)=m+\sqrt{x-m}$ on that interval. Hence $f$ is continuous on $(m,m+1)$. Since $m$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous on $\bigcup(m,m+1)=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$.

Now investigate what's going on at $x=m$. We have $f(m)=m$. We have seen that $f(x)$ equals $(m-1)+\sqrt{x-(m-1)}$ on the left of $x=m$ and $m+\sqrt{x-m}$ on the right. Since
$$
(m-1)+\sqrt{x-(m-1)}\to m\\
m+\sqrt{x-m}\to m
$$
as $x\to m^{-}$ and $x\to m^{+}$ respectively, we see that $f(x)\to f(m)$ as $x\to m$ and hence $f$ is continuous at $m$. Since $m$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Z}$.

All in all, $f$ is continuous on $(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z})\cup\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

⌊x⌋ is going to discontinuous - which doesn't mean that the whole function is discontinuous, only that $\sqrt{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$ has to be continuous, and that it has to "make up the difference".

⌊x⌋ is 'jumping' by 1 y-increment every 1 x-increment. Therefore, $\sqrt{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$ has to be continuous in 1 x-increment, and go from 0 to 1 continuously in this increment to 'make up' for the jump. We know that x - ⌊x⌋ is continuous from 0 to 1, repeating every 1 x-increment.

Therefore, all we need to prove is that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous with range 0 to 1 during the domain 0 to 1. That, at least, is something that is provable fairly easily in comparison.

Additionally, I used desmos.com to help me think through this, as they support the floor function, but it is notated as:

floor(x), where floor(x) = ⌊x⌋

Thanks, and please point out any mistakes I made. I am sorry I didn't mathmatically write out my proof, but from here it is hopefully simple translation.